# Ionic Serve on Chrome (Mac OSX) is slow

Tags: angularjs, macos, google-chrome, ionic-framework

I running on the last MacBook Pro 15 inch, and when I run "ionic serve" on Google Chrome, it's just impossible to develop on it, because it's pretty slow.

When i click on a button or something else, the action is triggered 1 min later (work find on real device or Safari).

If anybody can help me on this problem, because on Windows it's very okay :/

Thanks, good evening

Comment: i have exactly the same issue on Debian linux. No solution yet :(